# Sql request to find the MAX AVG

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I would like to get the max avg of data group by a column. I have a database built like this:

```
id | late | from 
---|------|--------
 1 |  13  |a
 2 |   3  |c
 3 |   2  |c
 4 |  27  |a
 5 |   7  |b
 6 |   9  |b
```

With that, I want to find the "from" who have the max avg of "late". Here it has to return"a":

```
 AVG(a) = ((13 + 27) / 2) = 20
 AVG(b) = ((7 + 9) / 2) = 8
 AVG(c) = ((3 + 2) / 2) = 2.5
```

I try  something like this :

```
SELECT id FROM Record HAVING MAX(AVG(late)) GROUP BY from
```

But it doesn't work...

Thank you for tour help !

Comment: You will need a nested query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  a `limit 1` on `order by  avg` in descending order:

```
select `from`
from my_table 
group by `from` 
order by avg(late) desc 
limit 1
```

But you should not use a column with a name such as `from`; not without escaping it that is, since it is a MySQL reserved word.